Using a DAX Query to calculate a maximum value for each of my projects from two tables in a many to one relationship
I have two tables:
Table 1



PROJECT_NUMBER
PROJECT_NAME




1
First Project


2
Second Project


3
Third Project



Table 2



PROJECT_NUMBER
MARKET
VALUE




1
Food
10


1
Retail
100


1
Fashion
200


2
Food
300


2
Retail
100


3
Fashion
500


3
Retail
10



Table 2 has a many to one relationship with Table 1, using the Project Number column.
The goal is that my final table shows me the following:
PROJECT_NUMBER PROJECT_NAME    MARKET VALUE ....
1              First Project   Fashion  200
2              Second Project  Food     300 
3              Third Project   Fashion  500

What I am getting now is a list of all the markets and a duplication of the projects for each market associated with them.
PROJECT_NUMBER PROJECT_NAME    MARKET VALUE ....
1              First Project   Food      10
1              First Project   Retail   100
1              First Project   Fashion  200
2              Second Project  Food     300
2              Second Project  Retail   100 
3              Third Project   Fashion  500
3              Third Project   Retail    10

I tried the following query, trying to replicate this post
MAX_VALUE = MAXX( FILTER('Table 2', 'Table 2'[PROJECT_NUMBER] = 'Table 1'[PROJECT_NUMBER]), 'Table 2'[VALUE])


In your table visual, do the following:

Set the MARKET column to First



Set the VALUE column to Maximum


Final Result:


You can create a CC to get the maximum market value per project :
MaxValuePerProject = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Table 2'[VALUE]), 
    ALLEXCEPT('Table 2', 'Table 2'[PROJECT_NUMBER])
)

and another one to flag  the rows with the maximum value :
IsMaxValue = 
IF('Table 2'[VALUE] = 'Table 2'[MaxValuePerProject], TRUE(), FALSE())


